# how can i get total number of customer who bought current configurbale or simple products in last 24 hrs

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, collection, product-view

I am in Product Detail Page. I want to show how many customers already had bought this product.

```
$time = time();
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$lastTime = $time - 86400; // 60*60*24
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);
$items = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to));
$soldCount = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
   $soldCount += $item->getQtyOrdered() - $item->getQtyCanceled() - $item->getQtyRefunded();
}
<?php if (count($soldCount) > 0):?>
  <div class="order-enticer button--l animated fadeInDown">Good Choice... 
       <b><?php echo $soldCount;?></b> 
       people have ordered this in the past 24 hours.</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your product `view.phtml`-

```
$time = time();
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$lastTime = $time - 86400; // 60*60*24
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);
$items = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('item_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('item_id', $_product->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to)); //filter with date to get only last 24 hours order


$soldCount = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $soldCount += $item->getQtyOrdered() - $item->getQtyCanceled() - $item->getQtyRefunded();
}
if($soldCount > 0){
    echo $soldCount.' people have purchased this product';
} else {
    echo 'Be the first to buy this product!';
}
```

Comment: Also i want to show, only total customers in past 24 hrs.

Comment: @gt06 please check my updated answer

Comment: not working...no error is displaying. A product is properly displaying.

Comment: can you update your question with code ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192654/get-total-number-of-customer-in-last-24-hrs-who-bought-the-products

Comment: I have updated my Question.

Comment: Please add your code too in the question

Comment: I have added code.

Comment: I have checked it in my system, it is working perfeclty, where did you added this code? add this code in `catalog/product/view.phtml`

Comment: I have to added in catalog/product/view/media.phtml. I have tried in view.phtml, but nothing happend.
Suppose I am on X product page. So I want to Show how many customer bought this X product in last 24 hrs.