# get total number of customer in last 24 hrs who bought the products

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, collection, product-view

I am on Product detail page. Suppose I am seeing X product. Now I want to show a total number of customers who bought this X product in last 24 hrs.

Last 24 hrs should be updated every day.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get all order collection which are purchased last 24 hours then from order collections you can easily get customer data.

To get Order Collection use below code:

```
    $time = time();
    $to_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
    $lastTime = $time - 86400; // 60*60*24
    $from_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);

    $orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from_date, 'to'=>$to_date))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));

    foreach($orderCollection as $order){
       $order->getCustomerEmail();     //this is customer email
       $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
       foreach($items as $i){
         echo $i->getProductId();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the count of Customers in last 24 hrs who bought current product?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which you can use on your product details page to get Number of customers who purchase current product.

```
<?php
$mySku = $_product->getSku();
$query = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection');
$query->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns(array('purchase_count'=>'COUNT(*)'))
        ->where(new Zend_Db_Expr('created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY AND NOW()'))
        ->where('sku = ?', $mySku)
        ->group(array('sku'));
$purchaseCount = $query->getColumnValues('purchase_count');

$customerCount = (is_array($purchaseCount) && !empty($purchaseCount)) ? $purchaseCount[0] : 0;
echo "$customerCount Customers have ordered this product in Past 24 hrs";
?>
```

Comment: nothing happend. I want to Paste this code in media.phml. Please help.

Comment: @gt06, please add updated code to your media file. It will show number of times the product is purchased yesterday.

Comment: nothing happend. If i purchase the item, still Purchase count is showing 0.

Comment: @gt06, please check now. It will give you product purchased in last 24 hours

Comment: nothing happend. It should also displayed that If count is 0, then displayed 0 Customers have ordered this product in Past 24 hrs, IF count > 0, count of customers have ordered this product in last 24 hrs.

Comment: @gt06, please check updated code, its tested on media.phtml file. Please note that this code will only work for simple products.

Comment: I want it for both Simple as well as configurable product.

Comment: @gt06, for that I can suggest you to get associated products of a configurable product and check those products and their order using the same code. Just try by yourself, if you face any difficulty, post your code and we will try to find a solution.